# php script for displaying Hours of Operation of a store is not working properly

Tags: php

I have a php script which I finally got with the help of friends and stackoverflow, where I am trying to display the hours of operation of a store such as it displays the current status whether it is open or not and the next staus as well. That means if the store is not open currently then when it will open next also needs to display. The script code is given below: it works some time when store is not opened currently and will open same day again (in case of Sunday, Thursday and Saturday when it opens twice a day), but it never works when it is currently closed and will now open on next day some time. It gives some error on last line of scrip and the error is :

***Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\karnalguide\operation-hrs-test.php on line 73***

I am making some mistake which I am not able to figure out - Please help me guys to fix this issue - check the error in script and help me with the fix. I am not much expert in php object oriented programming. So please explain me with full fix of this issue. Thanks in advance!

```
    <?php
/* Script for displaying operation times of a store and will be used in https://www.karnalguide.com */

/* array of store opening timings */
$storeSchedule = [
    'Sun' => [['12:00' => '01:00', '10:00' => '12:00']],
    'Mon' => [['09:00' => '12:00']],
    'Tue' => [['09:00' => '12:00']],
    'Wed' => [['09:00' => '12:00']],
    'Thu' => [['09:00' => '12:00'], ['22:50' => '23:00']],
    'Fri' => [['09:00' => '12:00']],
    'Sat' => [['12:00' => '01:00', '09:00' => '12:00']]
];

// current or user supplied UNIX timestamp
$timestamp = time();

// default status
$open = false;

// Open later at
$openAt = false;

// get current time object
$currentTime = (new DateTime())->setTimestamp($timestamp);

// Current day
$currentDay = date('D', $timestamp);

if(isset($storeSchedule[$currentDay])){

    // loop through time ranges for current day
    foreach ($storeSchedule[$currentDay] as $key => $dateGroup) {
        $startTime = current(array_keys($dateGroup));
        $endTime = current(array_values($dateGroup));


        // create time objects from start/end times
        $startTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $startTime);
        $endTime   = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $endTime);

        // check if current time is within a range
        if (($startTime < $currentTime) && ($currentTime < $endTime)) {
            $open = true;
            break;
        }elseif($currentTime < $startTime){
            // Opening Later
            $openAt = $startTime;
        }
    }
}else{
    // Not open because day is not in array

}


if($open){
    echo "We are open";
}else{
    if($openAt){
        echo "We open later at " . $openAt->format('H:i');
    }else{
        // Get next open
        $arrayDays = array_keys($storeSchedule);            // Get an array of the days
        $arrayTimes = array_values($storeSchedule);         // Get an array of times
        $dayIndex = array_search($currentDay, $arrayDays);  // Find out what day we are in in the array. To see if there are more this week
        $nextDay = ($dayIndex + 1) >= count($arrayDays) ? $arrayTimes[0] : $arrayTimes[$dayIndex + 1]; // If there are no more this week, take the first day, else take the next day.
        $nextOpenTime   = current(array_keys($nextDay));    // Take the first set of times from this day as the start time
        $nextOpenDay    = $arrayDays[$dayIndex + 1];        // Get the day key name


        echo "We are not open";
        echo "We open next on " . $nextOpenDay . " at " . $nextOpenTime->format('H:i');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: the mistake is in your last line, the `$nextOpenTime` object is null, because 3 lines above, the call to `currenbt(array_keys($nextDay))` returns null. It's up to you to debug your code line by line.

Comment: Thanks Pierre, I am able to figure out that the error is in the last line as shown line no. in the error and I have also traced it that current(array_keys($nextDay)) is returning 0 when I try to echo it. But how to fix it, I am not able to debug and find the error, or can I get this with help of some other piece of code. Please help me script work, if you can - thanks

Comment: **hint** `var_dump($nextDay)`

Comment: $nextDay is showing OK, the value of next day come Mon which is ok, but the problem is with the time i.e. at what time it will open on next day. means at what time it will open next on Mon. That is giving the error, I am not able to get that time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this code will do the same in a shorter way.
I loop today and see if it's open or will open today.
If it's not open I dump the next day but that can easily be replaced with a echo.

```
$storeSchedule = [
    'Sun' => [['12:00' => '01:00', '10:00' => '12:00']],
    'Mon' => [['09:00' => '12:00']],
    'Tue' => [['09:00' => '12:00']],
    'Wed' => [['09:00' => '12:00']],
    'Thu' => [['09:00' => '12:00'], ['22:50' => '23:00']],
    'Fri' => [['09:00' => '12:00']],
    'Sat' => [['12:00' => '01:00', '09:00' => '12:00']]
];
$today = date("D");
$closed = Null;
foreach($storeSchedule[$today] as $opentimes){
    foreach($opentimes as $open => $close){
        $now = time();

        if($now > strtotime(date("Y-m-d" . $open)) && $now < strtotime(date("Y-m-d" . $close))){
            echo "store open now";
            $closed = false;
        }else if($now < strtotime(date("Y-m-d" . $open))){
            echo "store will open at " . date("Y-m-d" . $open);
            $closed = false;
        }else{
            // Store is closed 
            if($closed !== false) $closed = true;
        }
     }
}

if($closed){
    // Dump the next open time
    var_dump($storeSchedule[date("D",strtotime($today)+86400)]);
}
```

https://3v4l.org/DAvmo

Comment: Thanks Andreas, but it is just returning array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["09:00"]=> string(5) "12:00" } }  and showing the same on screen instead of next day open date and time. When i use eacho then also it shows the same . Please help how to display actualy date & time of next day open. please write code. Thanks.

Comment: Since the store is open every day it's easy to just say it's open tomorrow. But I must say your array is very hard to use. But this is what I mean: https://3v4l.org/vf0kb

Comment: Wow... Thanks a lot Andreas ! my work is done, its working as per my requirement. Great help... Thanks once again.